# TYPO3: get all FE users

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I am trying to create a user management module. I would like to get all FE users.

This is my Controller:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $feUserRepository;
```

then I use:

```
$users = $this->feUserRepository->findAll();

$this->view->assign('users', $users);
```

but all I get is an empty object.

EDIT:

for some reason

```
$this->feUserRepository->findByUId(1);
```

does work but findAll() not...

Answer (score 1):

This is because extbase will silently disable the `respectStoragePage` setting on the querySettings for a `findByUid($uid)` call.

So, you have two options:

1. Provide the correct storage pid in the TypoScript configuration of your plugin (`plugin.tx_myextension.persistence.storagePid`). This way,  you will find every frontenduser that is stored on the given page.
2. You could implement your own `FrontendUserRepository` that extends the repository from extbase but disables the `respectStoragePage` for all calls (this way you'll get every frontendUser regardless of the page the record is stored on). Here is how you do it:

   ```
   use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository as ExtbaseFrontendUserRepository;

   class FrontendUserRepository extends ExtbaseFrontendUserRepository
   {
       /**
        * Disable respecting of a storage pid within queries globally.
        */
       public function initializeObject()
       {
           $defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings:class);
           $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
           $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);
       }
   }
   ```

In your Controller you then inject your `FrontendUserRepository`. Then you should do the same for the `FrontendUser` Model and tell extbase afterwards that you are using the fe_users table for your Model:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, tank you!

Comment: If it is just a onetime thing, you can edit the query after you "execute" it, because the query is not actually executed until the data is needed, therefore this works: ``$users->getQuery()->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);``. You do not need to extend the repository for this, although it might be cleaner to do so.

Comment: We should the `config` typoscript be placed in?